# Excess child elements when parsing XML in Java

Tags: java, xml

I have the XML-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<questions>
    <question>
        <name>First question</name>
        <true>2</true>
        <answers>
            <answer>First answer</answer>
            <answer>Second answer</answer>
            <answer>Third answer</answer>
            <answer>Fourth answer</answer>
        </answers>
    </question>
    <question>
        <name>Second question</name>
        <true>3</true>
        <answers>
            <answer>First answer</answer>
            <answer>Second answer</answer>
            <answer>Third answer</answer>
            <answer>Fourth answer</answer>
        </answers>
    </question>
</questions>
```

Why when the Java code below is executed, it returns 9 elements instead of 4, and the incorrect 5 elements contain one line feed and 3 tabs that are between `<answers>` and `<answer>` (one), `</answer>` and `<answer>` (three), `</answer>` and `</answers>` (one) in XML:

```
File file = new File(path);
DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = documentBuilder.parse(file);
NodeList answers = doc.getElementsByTagName("answers").item(n).getChildNodes();
```

Next, I do a check to cut off the wrong elements:

```
if (answers.item(i).getTextContent().trim().length() > 0)
```

I would be grateful if you could tell me a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not returning 9 *elements* - it's returning 9 *nodes*, which is correct. (After all, you're asking for the child nodes of the `answers` element.) Those white-space only text nodes are valid nodes. If you want elements, just ignore any node where `Node.getNodeType()` doesn't return `Node.ELEMENT_NODE`.

Alternatively, just call `getElementsByTagName("answer")` on the `answers` element to get just the elements. That's assuming you're happy to ignore any non-`answer` elements though. For example:

```java
Element answersElement = (Element) doc.getElementsByTagName("answers").item(n);
NodeList answerElements = answersElement.getElementsByTagName("answer");
```

Comment: In the second method, I can only get a specific answer or all answers, but I need a list of answers to a specific question.

Comment: @Sergei: Please re-read my suggestion, you call `getElementsByTagName("answer")` *on the `answers` element you're trying to find the answers from*. Not on the document.